# Zip file download system laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, download, zip

**I'm using Laravel 8**

I've uploaded a zip file then want to download it. But here is a problem. After file download, it's not extracting.

Here is my code for download zip file:

```
                $product = Product::where('id',1)->first();
                $file = $product->main_file;
                return response()->download($file,'filename.zip');
```

But, if I manually copy this zip file from my project then extract it, it's extracting fine.

Or, if I doing this: `return Redirect()->to($file);` It also downloads the file and extracts well without any problem. But, it's not a proper way to download. Isn't it?

**So, What can I do now?**

Comment: What do you mean "it's not extracting"? Is your downloaded zip file corrupted? What does its content look like?

Comment: @meyegui, I think so. It's a download zip file but corrupted.

Comment: If you open it with a text editor, does it contain binary data or an HTML error message?

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to download via a link try this:

```
<a href="{{$zipfile}}" download="{{$zipfile}}">Download</a>
```

but file name should be saved somewhere.